# authenticate to another site using a login form on my site

Tags: login, forms

I am trying to use a login form on my website to authenticate to another online system. for example i want to use a simple form on an university site to login to https://www.ubt.esse3.u-gov.rash.al/Home.do

Answer (score 0):

First, as your example links are using website developed using Java, so this is not the exact forum for asking the question.

BTW, If you are owner of both website and have access to database coding and session handling code, you can do this by changing the database connection and writing the same code in widget.